# How can I use django template variable with filter(safe) as an argument to call javascript function?

Tags: javascript, python, django, django-templates

This is my javascript function :

```
function change(text){
                 var value = text;
              }
```

This is my HTML code:

```
<a href="#" id="toggleButton" class='media-text' onclick="change('{{itm.title}}')">More</a>
```

Now the above code works until I add "safe" filter to my django variable. When I'm calling the change function like this `change('{{itm.description|safe}}')` it doesn't works.

Comment: Doesn't work means? Are you getting unexpected output? Any syntax error?

Comment: Yeah I got "Unexpected token ILLEGAL " error.

Comment: You seem to be missing quotes around `{{}}` there.

Comment: Then that should have worked. What's there in `description`?

Comment: Its a content rendered from "ckeditor"

Comment: Can you print it's value without safe filter?